# replacing dnsmasq w/ systemd-resolved - alternative to 'address' directive

Tags: linux, networking, dns, systemd, dnsmasq

Been using dnsmasq for ages - mostly for local caching and blocking out dubious domains.
Now I have need for split-DNS, so it's time to switch to systemd-resolved.

One major feature I'm using from dnsmasq are the `address` directives to blacklist domains. I have a daemon script that periodically composes `/etc/dnsmasq.d/malware.conf` that has a list of rules like

```
address=/baddomain1.com/0.0.0.0/
address=/baddomain2.com/0.0.0.0/
...
```

How to replicate this logic using `systemd-resolved`?

Comment: Why not just use `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Needs additional logic to maintain the file - /etc/hosts doesn't allow includes.

Comment: Doesn't dnsmasq also support split-dns through `server=`?

Comment: @user1686 you're correct, but believe it'd also need additional active management when you have corporate ~DNS~ VPN you may or may not be connected to.

Answer (score 0):

In systemd's world you have [systemd.resource-control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.resource-control.html), a unit settings dedicated to resource control.

by example, you can also apply this in emergency:

```sh
systemctl set-property apache2.service IPAddressDeny=85.32.3.0/24
```